# Can I join these 2 oracle queries?

Tags: sql, oracle

Can i join these 2 oracle queries to give me my desired output:

```
| RLI1 | RLI2 | Catalog | Os_type |
|_ _ _ | _ _ _| _ _ _ _ | _ _ _ _ |
|_ _ _ | _ _ _| _ _ _ _ | _ _ _ _ |
```

I dont have rights to change anything in the DB because its remote, I just extracting 4 data but there are two queries for it.

so 1. Is this possible 2. Alternatives?

```
SELECT 
rli.resevation_id        AS "RLI1",
rli.reservation_ln_id    AS "RLI2"
FROM 
UCS_USER.RESOURCETYPES RT,
UCS_USER.MASTERRESOURCETYPES MRT,
UCS_USER.RESERVATIONLINEITEMS RLI,
UCS_USER.RESERVATION R,
UCS_USER.CUSTOMER C,
UCS_USER.STATUS_CODE S,
UCS_USER.orchestrationtasksstatus t,
UCS_USER.state_code code,
UCS_USER.ORCHESTRATIONPROCESS o,
UCS_USER.ORCHESTRATIONTASKS tasks,
UCS_USER.MASTER_ORCHESTRATION_TASKS mot

WHERE 
RLI.RESEVATION_ID        = R.RESEVATION_ID
AND r.customer_id              = c.customer_id
AND RT.MASTER_RESOURCE_TYPE_ID = MRT.MASTER_RESOURCE_TYPE_ID
AND RLI.RESOURCE_TYPE_ID       = RT.RESOURCE_TYPE_ID
AND RLI.STATUS                 = S.STATUS_ID
AND RLI.reservation_ln_id      =O.reservation_ln_id
AND o.process_id               = t.process_id
AND t.state_id                 = code.state_id
AND o.orch_type_id             = tasks.orch_type_id
AND tasks.master_orchtask_id   =mot.master_orchtask_id
AND o.process_id               = t.process_id
AND t.state_id                 = code.state_id
AND t.task_id                  =tasks.task_id
and o.process_id = (select max(op.process_id) from UCS_USER.orchestrationprocess op  where op.reservation_ln_id = RLI.reservation_ln_id)
AND rli.DATA_CENTER in  ('ATC01','SYZ01','TUBCDC1','BLX01','SPH01','EBM01','TLJ02','CA001','IDA01- 03','LL139','NL195','IT100','SP102','SG181')
AND (c.name not like '%Test%' AND c.name not like '00 CPE CUSTOMER' AND (c.name not like '%UAT%'  OR c.name = 'ECS SAP UAT'))
AND (s.status_name LIKE '%Clean-up Underway%'
OR s.status_name like '%Provisioning Underway%')
AND (code.state_name LIKE '%Errors%'
OR code.state_name LIKE '%failure%')
ORDER BY t.process_id DESC
```

Now I want to pass it to the last line of the query 2:

```
SELECT 
ci.catalog_item_name AS catalog_item,lnop.value AS os_type, 
FROM
UCS_USER.ln_options_at_readytosignoff lnop,UCS_USER.reservationlineitems rli,UCS_USER.order_item oi,UCS_USER.catalog_item ci
WHERE 
lnop.quote_ln_id=rli.quote_ln_id
and rli.order_item_id=oi.order_item_id
and oi.catalog_item_id = ci.catalog_item_id
and lnop.option_name like '%Type%'
and rli.ln_type=1
and rli.reservation_ln_id in(select a.reservation_ln_id from reservationlineitems a
left join reservationlineitems b on a.reservation_ln_id = b.depends_on
where (a.reservation_ln_id =RLI1 or b.reservation_ln_id=RLI2))
```

I want to pass value (rli1 and rli2) from query 1 to the "< >":

```
where (a.reservation_ln_id = < query1.rli1 > or b.reservation_ln_id= < query1.rli2 >))
```

Comment: Second query missing alias.

Comment: Edited my 2nd query, I want to insert RLI1 and RLI2 at the last line. Is it possible?

Comment: CTE- Common Table Expressions

Comment: Apparently they do not. So when I tried UNION ALL. There's an error well maybe because they don't have the same number of columns. The first query is a very specific number and using this in the second query I can output its OS.

Comment: if you want to use union, you can fill missing columns with the right datatype `SELECT string1, string2, int1, int2 table1 UNION SELECT '', '', 0, 0 FROM table2 `

Comment: IF I use CTE, how do you pass the value of query1's output to query2's requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Subquery [Subquery Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/subqueries.html)

```
SELECT value1, value2, subquery.rli1, subquery.rli2 FROM query2,
( SELECT rli1,rli2 FROM query1) subquery
WHERE value1 = subquery.rli1 and value2 = subquery.rli2
```